# Given an IBOutlet pointer in Objective-C/iPad, how do you hide that element?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Given an IBOutlet pointer in Objective-C/iPad, how do you hide that element?  Want to remove it from the screen by making it invisible, hiding it, removing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
object.alpha = 0.0;

object.hidden = YES;

[self.view removeSubview:object];
```

The alpha one can be used within animation blocks for some useful effects.